# Extending a user in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to extend a [User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/) class and write a serializer for it using django rest framework, I am trying to add `mobileNumber` field to `User`. Following is the code I am using:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ValidateMeUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobileNumber = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import serializers
from phone.models import ValidateMeUser

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','password')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}, }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user


class ValidateMeUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ValidateMeUser
        fields = ('mobileNumber','user')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)
        validateMeUser = ValidateMeUser.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return validateMeUser
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from phone.serializers import ValidateMeUserSerializer
from phone.models import ValidateMeUser

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def user_list(request):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = ValidateMeUser.objects.all()
        serializer = ValidateMeUserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ValidateMeUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from phone import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list/$', views.user_list),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

When I run the curl command I get following message:

```
curl --data "username=user123455&password=sdasd&mobileNumber=2618221" http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/

{"user":{"username":["This field is required."],"password":["This field is required."]}}
```

It seems to me that the UserSerializer is either not getting called or not getting initialized properly. Can anyone help me out what might be causing this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a nested serializer and provide flat data.
If you want to keep data flat, you'll only need one serializer and add the extra fields to it:

```
class ValidateMeUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(...)
    email = serializers.CharField(...)
    password = serializers.CharField(...)

    class Meta:
        model = ValidateMeUser
        fields = ('mobileNumber', 'username', 'email', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data.pop('username')
        ...
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, ...)
        validateMeUser = ValidateMeUser.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return validateMeUser
```

Comment: it solved half of the issue, I am able to create a ValidateMeUser user now. But in the response I still get error. " 'ValidateMeUser' object has no attribute 'username' ". Which is right as we are using User class for construction of ValidateMeUser. The error is for both 'GET' and 'POST'. And this is originated from "site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py in get_attribute, line 70". this is when serializer.data is called.

Comment: For now as a hack I modified ValidateMeUserSerializer's name as ValidateMeUserListSerializer from original serializers.py which I posted. And used this seriallizer just for listing. I still use ValidateMeUserSerializer provided by you for 'POST' calls. 

In view.py I removed serializer.data from 'POST' return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

and changed ValidateMeUserSerializer to ValidateMeUserListSerializer in 'GET' 

The hack became a bit messy but , working. Could you let me know if there is any good way to solve this issue? Thanks, Kunal

Comment: I have no idea what your code looks like. Sounds like you didn't pop the username attribute from the validated_data.